# Match updated properties of geometrically identical Revit models

Tags: revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative

Given 2 Revit models that look identical but have differences in their property (for example the uniqueid is different) how can I know which elements have updated uniqueids, even though their spatial configuration hasn't changed?

I've seen tools that allow to detect differences in geometry or changes of properties on the same model, but what if we have two completely different models, how can I match the properties of the elements, if their spatial configuration is the same (ie position, dimension, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that as with all good questions, the answer is contained in the question itself. You can use the similarities in location, geometry and other properties to detect whether two objects in different BIMs ought to be considered equal or not. Using that (almost, or mostly) invariant information, you can [create your own key](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/03/great-ocean-road-and-creating-your-own-key.html#2), use that to determine relationships between similar or identical objects, and then build on that further to determine the differences as well as the similarities.

Comment: What would be the best tools to do this? Revit APIs, Dinamo, Forge...?

Comment: I am not aware of any tool called Dinamo. Do you mean Dynamo? Forge no longer exists eiither; it  is now named APS, the Autodesk Platform Services. It totally depends on your use case.  APS is a cloud service, so no local Revit installation is needed. Dynamo builds on top of the Revit API and is a wrapper for that. Probably the Revit API is the simplest way to go for the situation described above,.